# Passing related entity to a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the entities 'Reserve' , 'ReservesUsers' and the default 'ApplicationUser'.

```
public class Reserve
{        
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Begin { get; set; }
    public string End { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; } //free , reserved, confirmed, canceled
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ReserveUser> ReservesUsers { get; set; }
}

public class ReserveUser
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
            
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public int ReserveId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ReserveId")]
    public Reserve Reserve { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public bool IsProfessional { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ReserveUser> ReservesUsers { get; set; }
}
```

As I need the users and the reserve in the view, I get it:

```
var usersByReserve = _context.Reserves
            .Where(m => m.ID == id)
            .Include(ru => ru.ReservesUsers)
                .ThenInclude(ap => ap.User)
            .ToList();
```

How can I send it to the view and access it.

I tried:

```
return View(usersByReserve);
```

and did not worked.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Reservation.Models.Reserve]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Reservation.Models.Reserve'.
> EnsureCompatible

Comment: did not work ? Are you getting an error ? How does your view code looks like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code will return a **collection** of `Reserve` class objects (matching your where clause) to the view. But **your view is expecting a single instance of Reserve class**.  Even if your where clause is condition results in a single record, It will still return a collection of one item because `Where` method returns a collection.

Since you are looking for a single item(matching your where clause condition), you may use the `FirstOrDefault` method to get that.

```
var usersByReserve = _context.Reserves
            .Where(m => m.ID == id)
            .Include(ru => ru.ReservesUsers)
            .ThenInclude(ap => ap.User)
            .FirstOrDefault();
if(usersByReserve !=null)
{
  return View(usersByReserve);
}
else
{
  //return a "not found message/view"
  return Content("No item found for the id passed");
}
```

Now, you need to make your view strongly typed to Reserve class and then you can access the properties as needed.

```
@model Reserve
<h1> @Model.Begin </h1>
@if(Model.ReservesUsers!=null)
{
  <p>Some ReservesUsers found</p>
  @foreach(var u in Model.ReservesUsers)
  {
    <p>@u.UserId </p>
  }
}
else
{
  <p>No ReservesUsers found!</p>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shyju, I just did some modifications in order to work, first i replaces '@model Reserve' with '@model IEnumerable<Reservation.Models.Reserve>'  , second  I added a nested for loop: '@foreach' (var item in Model)
{
    foreach (var user in item.ReservesUsers)
    {
        '@user.User.Email'
    }    
}

Comment: @UgoAugustoGustavoGuazelli yea. That will work if you want to show more than one reserve items in the page.  You don't need firstordefault call then.